# How can I send data from Winform to a VB6 form?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6

I've been reading a lot about using SendMessage to accomplish what I'm trying to do so forgive me if there is other documentation out there pertaining to this.

I have an older CRM application (Surado CRM) that is built with VB6.  I'm guessing VB6 because of the ThunderRT6 class names that WinSpy is returning.

I have a small Winform application built that so far sends some key strokes to open up a blank ticket window.  Now I'm stuck at trying to taking data from a  maskedTextBox in the Winform app and sending it to a ThunderRT6TextBox in the VB6 application.

Is this possible?   Is SendMessage a correct approach?  If so could someone help me out with some pseudo code of sorts?

Comment: Yep, specifically you want to send the `WM_SETTEXT` message. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100605).

Comment: Well been almost a year but I haven't really gotten back into this app as it's more or less a side project.  But I've experimented with SendMessage and can send messages to Notepad and calculator. But in both of those programs I only have to go through 1 child window  before I can call SendMessage.  In my app there is 4 children and the last child also has other windows of the same class, ThunderRT6TextBox.   I'm having a heck of a time trying to traverse from the main window.  Any suggestions?  I've been scouring the net and can't come up with anything that will help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any advice to give you. Other than to stay vigilant, because just like scraping 30 layers deem in the DOM of an HTML page, it can be a pain, but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks man.  I appreciate your feedback.